# ShouId I use "how is your weekend looking" or "how is your weekend looks like"?

Tags: questions, idiomatic-language

Which one idiomatic?

1. How is your weekend looking?
2. How is your weekend looks like?

I have seen the first one more often. However, I feel that the word "like" should be added at the end.

Comment: "What does your weekend look like is" ok, and "How does your weekend look" is also ok. But "How is ... looks like" is not correct in any situation I can think of

Comment: It's a very slangy / colloquial usage anyway, so I wouldn't worry too much about concepts like "correct syntax" here. But unless you use this colloquial idiomatic form it's not easy to convey the *exact* meaning succinctly. *What does it look like your weekend will be like?* is a bit clumsy, and *How is your weekend shaping up?* would usually imply ***...so far*** (i.e. - the weekend has already started). Note that your example #2 is completely invalid. *What's your weekend looking like?* is "okay".

Comment: Vlad, please. **What does your dog look like**? He is brown and white with a long tail. For look like, the question is formed like any other question in the simple present...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic ways to say this:

- What **'s** your weekend looking like?
- What **does** your weekend look like?
- What is your weekend looking like? [long form]

with **HOW**:

- How's your weekend looking?
- How does your weekend look?
- How is your weekend looking? [long form]

Suggestion: Memorize these forms.

to look like [something]:**What does X look like**? **How does X look?**

Do not use the *how* form with the word **like** here.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How is your weekend looking?

> 2. How is your weekend looks like?

Example 2 is ungrammatical.

An attempt to find 'how is your weekend looking' in [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=How+is+your+weekend+%2A&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHow%20is%20your%20weekend%20going%3B%2Cc0) got me 'how is your weekend going' instead.